# Question related to the Coupon Collector's Problem.

Tags: probability

What is the expected number of tosses of a coin to get both sides at least once ?

The answer is 3.

When I run a simulation of a large series of random 0s and 1s it can be observed that the average number of tosses to get both a 0 and a 1 is indeed 3.

But my issue arises when I draw the outcomes using a tree diagram.

After 2 tosses the probability that a Head and a Tail occurred is 0.5. After three tosses the probability that at least one of each occurred is 0.75.

Would it be true to say that for the Coupon Collector's Problem the probability must be greater than 0.5 and that 0.5 is not sufficient ?

Comment: Toss the coin the first time.  *It will be something and it doesn't matter what it was*.  Whatever it was in the first toss, we are now just looking for the other side of the coin to occur.  That is a standard geometric probability distribution at this point which we know from earlier example simply has expected value $1/p$ or in this case $2$.  Adding to the first flip, the expected value is then $1+2=3$

Comment: "*After 3 tosses...at least one of each occurred is $0.75$*" sure... but keep in mind that among those cases several would not have required the third toss.  The probability the third toss is required and it ends on the third toss would only have been $\frac{1}{4}$.  As for your final sentence, I have no idea what you are talking about.  "*for the coupon collector's problem the probability must be greater than $0.5$ and that $0.5$ is not sufficient?*"  What probability are you talking about?  Sufficient for what?

Comment: The fact that the probability of getting both sides in $3$ tosses is equal to $0.75$ isn't an issue, since you are interested in the \emph{expected} value. It can be less than $3$ (here $2$), but it can be more than $3$. But if you express the probability that you have one side for $(n-1)$ tosses and the other side on the $n$-th toss, you can then sum $n$ times such probability to get the expected value, which will be $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete expected value formula is
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} x\cdot\mathrm{P}(x)$$
So, let $X$ be the number of tosses until we see both a heads and a tails, letting $\mathrm{P}(\text{Coin lands heads})=p$. So after one flip, the probability that we have seen both heads and tails is obviously zero. Formally,
$\mathrm{P}(1)=0$. How about after two flips? The *event space* after two flips is $\{\text{HH, HT, TH, TT}\}$. The individual probabilities of these four events are $p^2, p(1-p), p(1-p)$, and $(1-p)^2$. Therefore,
$$\mathrm{P}(2)=2p(1-p).$$
How about after three flips? Well, considering we've gotten this far, the only possible prior strings of flips are $\text{HH}$ and $\text{TT}$. After one more flip, there are four possible outcomes: $\{\text{HHH, HHT, TTH, TTT}\}$. The middle two contain both heads and tails and their respective probabilities are $p^2(1-p)$ and $(1-p)^2$. So,
$$\mathrm{P}(3)=p^2(1-p)+(1-p)^2 p=p(1-p)\left(p+(1-p)\right)$$
After four flips,
$$\mathrm{P}(4)=p^3(1-p)+(1-p)^3 p=p(1-p)\left(p^2+(1-p)^2\right)$$
This pattern continues. After $n$ flips,
$$\mathrm{P}(n)=p(1-p)\left(p^{n-2}+(1-p)^{n-2}\right)$$
So our expected value sum is
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n\cdot p(1-p)\left(p^{n-2}+(1-p)^{n-2}\right))$$
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=p(1-p)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+2)p^m + \sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+2)(1-p)^m\right)$$
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=p(1-p)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty m\cdot p^m +2\sum_{m=0}^\infty p^m +\sum_{m=0}^\infty m\cdot (1-p)^m+2\sum_{m=0}^\infty (1-p)^m\right)$$
Two of these sums are simple geometric series, however for the other two it can be shown that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\cdot t^k=\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$$
For $|t|<1$. Thus,
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=p(1-p)\left(\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}+2\frac{1}{1-p}+\frac{1-p}{(1-(1-p))^2}+2\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}\right)$$
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=p(1-p)\left(\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}+\frac{1-p}{p^2}+2\left(\frac{1}{1-p}+\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)$$
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=\frac{p^2}{(1-p)}+\frac{(1-p)^2}{p}+2$$
In the case of a fair coin, i.e $p=1/2$, this is
$$\mathrm{E}(X)=\frac{(1/2)^2}{1/2}+\frac{(1/2)^2}{1/2}+2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+2=3$$
Which confirms the results of your experimentation.